# How to ask drush to add timestamps to output?

Tags: drush

Some of the steps in our drush-make process take a while and having timestamps in the build-log would be useful -- for every line.

Is there a way to do this already, perhaps? The `DRUSH_BACKEND` pieces of JSON contain timestamps (seconds since Unix epoch), but they aren't shown for *every* step. Perhaps, there is something like a `--timestamp` flag in drush already?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look this is possible. There is a list of available commands for drush make here: http://www.drushcommands.com/drush-7x/make/make